swap one column with a subset of the headers with pandas
i want to convert the elements into a single column. i have tried pivot and pivot table and because i have duplicates it doesnt allow, i have also tried melting



University id #
Year
financial_period
element #1
element #2
element #3




1
2022
prior_year
$1
$3
$2


1
2022
current_year
$2
$5
$0



This is what I'm trying to get



University id #
Year
fin_element
prior_year
current_year




1
2022
element #1
$1
$2


1
2022
element #2
$3
$5


1
2022
element #3
$2
$0



i have tried
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:2], value_vars='element')

which moves the elements into columns, but i can't figure out how to turn financial period into column headers

I think it would be clearer to describe the problem as you want to swap one column with a subset of the headers. At least, that's how I interpreted it. You could [edit] to clarify if you want. See [ask] for tips on how to write a good title (and more tips for future questions).

@wjandrea thanks for the advice, edited the title

You can solve this with .set_index(), unstack() (to pivot financial_period) and .stack() (to pivot fin_element), plus a few additional touchups.
(
    df
    .set_index(['University id #', 'Year', 'financial_period'])
    .rename_axis('fin_element', axis=1)
    .unstack('financial_period')
    .stack('fin_element')
    .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)

   University id #  Year fin_element prior_year current_year
0                1  2022  element #1         $1           $2
1                1  2022  element #2         $3           $5
2                1  2022  element #3         $2           $0

This sort of technique is also covered at How can I pivot a dataframe? (overly broad canonical question). See also the user guide: Reshaping and pivot tables.
Intermediate steps
After unstack
fin_element            element #1              element #2              element #3           
financial_period     current_year prior_year current_year prior_year current_year prior_year
University id # Year                                                                        
1               2022           $2         $1           $5         $3           $0         $2

After stack and sort
financial_period                 prior_year current_year
University id # Year fin_element                        
1               2022 element #1          $1           $2
                     element #2          $3           $5
                     element #3          $2           $0


why does it work for you when there's duplicate entries in index however i get ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

@kkk Are you using different data than you posted in the question? If so, could you post a gist or a pastebin? I'll take a look and see what the difference is. If not, what version of Pandas are you using? I'm using 2.0.3

your method might work but due to time constraints i resorted to using power query unpivot function to achieve this, will definitely come back to problem one day. Thanks for your help!

Or, we can use pd.wide_to_long with a little reshaping:
pd.wide_to_long(df, 'element', ['University id #', 'Year', 'financial_period'], 'fin_element', suffix='.*')['element']\
  .rename(lambda x: 'element'+x, level=3).unstack(2).reset_index()

Output:
financial_period  University id #  Year fin_element current_year prior_year
0                               1  2022  element #1           $2         $1
1                               1  2022  element #2           $5         $3
2                               1  2022  element #3           $0         $2


I have used melt and pivot to get the output
df_melted = df.melt(
    id_vars=['University id #', 'Year', 'financial_period'], 
    value_vars=['element #1', 'element #2', 'element #3'], 
    var_name='fin_element', 
    value_name='value')

# Pivot the 'financial_period' column to make each period a new column
df_pivoted = df_melted.pivot_table(
    index=['University id #', 'Year', 'fin_element'], 
    columns='financial_period', 
    values='value', 
    aggfunc='first').reset_index()

# Flatten the columns
df_pivoted.columns.name = None  # Remove the columns' name
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.rename_axis(None, axis=1)  # Remove the index name

print(df_pivoted)

Output:
   University id #  Year fin_element current_year prior_year
0                1  2022  element #1           $2         $1
1                1  2022  element #2           $5         $3
2                1  2022  element #3           $0         $2

Setup for reference:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'University id #': [1, 1],
    'Year': [2022, 2022],
    'financial_period': ['prior_year', 'current_year'],
    'element #1': ['$1', '$2'],
    'element #2': ['$3', '$5'],
    'element #3': ['$2', '$0'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

